# Java .torrent file download

Tags: java, file, encoding

I want to download a .torrent file from this link 
http://torrage.com/torrent/13764753227BCBE3E8E82C058A7D5CE2BDDF9857.torrent
to do this I use this code

```
URL website = new URL(link);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
File f = new File(path+"t2.torrent");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
```

Now, when I open it in utorrent i get this message : Unable to load "t2.torrent": torrent is not a valid bencoding!

From what I read on internet I learnd that this files have a special encoding.
What is the propper way to download end encode this kind of file.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the torrent file becomes corrupted is that the web server you are downloading it from provides it in compressed (gzipped) format. You can unzip it in Java using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(link);
try (InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream())) {
  Files.copy(is, Paths.get(path + "t2.torrent"));
}
```